# python: subset a nested list if matches in another list

Tags: python, list, nested, subset, traversal

Say I have represented a n row x m columns-matrix as a nested python list, e.g. 3 rows and 2 columns:

```
m = [ [1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'] ]
```

What will be a generic and pythonic way to generate another k x m-matrix (k <= n) with rows where values in, say, the second column have matches in a sequence (that is a subset of `m`). 
Thus for the sequence below there are matches for 'a' and 'c':

```
s = ['j', 'a', 'c', 'e']
```

The resulting matrix `m2`should be

```
m2 = [ [1,3], ['a','c'] ]
```

---

**What did not work:**

My stupid try was something along (which generate error/did not work, and is less scalable for many columns):

```
m2 = [ [x, y] for x, y in m if y in s ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` the rows of `m` to identify columns whose second item is present in `s`, and `zip` the columns again to output the rows:

```
list(zip(*(c for c in zip(*m) if c[1] in s)))
```

This returns:

```
[(1, 3), ('a', 'c')]
```

If you need the output to be a list of lists, you can map the tuples generated by `zip` to `list`:

```
list(map(list, list(zip(*(c for c in zip(*m) if c[1] in s)))))
```

This returns:

```
[[1, 3], ['a', 'c']]
```

You can optionally make `s` a set first to improve lookup efficiency if there are many items in `s`:

```
s = set(s)
```

Comment: Ah sorry - I was not paying attention when accepting. I tried to only select on column 2 in `m`. Your code wrongly returns `[(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')]` when  `s = ['j', 'a', 'c', 'e', 2]` because `1`has a match in first column of m.

Comment: So is the column number of 2 a fixed number? Or is it the last column?

Comment: Lets say its fixed

Comment: Perfect man! My head breaks when I try to use these comprehensions. Great explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m2 = [[], []]

for i in range(len(m[1])):
    if m[1][i] in s:
        m2[0].append(m[0][i])
        m2[1].append(m[1][i])
```